# Entity Framework Attach not updating collection changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When updating the Viewers collection with a reference to a User with the Id correctly set the DB is not updated with this new reference. All other fields are updated but the collections are not updated.

```
var entity = new Event
{
    Id = model.Id,
    Name = model.Name,
    Date = model.Date,
    Location = model.Location,
    EBroadcasters = model.Broadcasters?.Select(b => new User
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        SkypeId = b.SkypeId,
        Name = b.Name,
        ServiceUrl = b.ServiceUrl
    }).ToList(),
    EViewers = model.Viewers?.Select(v => new User
    {
        Id = v.Id,
        SkypeId = v.SkypeId,
        Name = v.Name,
        ServiceUrl = v.ServiceUrl
    }).ToList()
};

_ssRepository.Events.Attach(entity);
_ssRepository.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

// Don't think I need to do this stuff but tried everything to get it to update!!!
foreach (var b in entity.EBroadcasters)
{
    _ssRepository.Users.Attach(b);
    _ssRepository.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

foreach (var v in entity.EViewers)
{
    _ssRepository.Users.Attach(b);
    _ssRepository.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

_ssRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Gerard

Comment: Navigation properties are only set during relationship fixup, which is not done when simply attaching entries to their corresponding DbSets I believe, but only when retrieving values from the database. You'll have to do the join in-memory or retrieve the saved entries with a clean DbContext.

Comment: it should not be necessary to attach child elements, but other than that, your code looks fine and it should work for you. Check if your mappings are correct and check if primary key values are correct.

Comment: I have checked the PKs they are correct. I have had this issue since EF6. It seems that using the `new` keyword means that a new row will be created in the DB no matter what.